# Can we use HYPERLINK FORMULA field in salesforce 1?

Tags: formula, hyperlink

I have created a HYPERLINK formula

```
HYPERLINK("/apex/my_VF_Page?Id="+ Id , "MY VF Page" )
```

If I use link in saleforce 1 App.  This link doesn't work any workaround so I add any logic in HYPERLINK for redirect to VF page in saleforce 1App.

Any Idea if we can use `sforce.one.navigateToURL` or something

```
javascript:sforce.one.navigateToURL('/apex/SimpleSiteProgram?id='+Id)
```

Comment: you can use detail page link.

Comment: @TusharSharma can you please add this solution as ans if I don't get any other solution with HYPERLINK formula then I will accept your ans thanks.

Comment: I've had a similar issue with the Salesforce1 app. If I go to the browser on my phone and login to salesforce, my links work fine. It seems to be isolated to the app, for me at least.

Comment: @sfdcweb I have added my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure about the hyperlink formula but you can use detail page link. from there you can do your redirect stuff.

To add Detail page Link follow these simple steps.

1. go to Setup>Customize>Object>Buttons, Links, and Actions, and click New Button or Link. Give your link a name,
2. In case of custom object go to Setup>Create > Object>Buttons, Links, and Actions, and click New Button or Link. Give your link a name,
   [image]
3. Now go to detail page of record and click on Edit layout and drop your link to suitable place. Now view in the salesforce one.
   [image]

Note: Image are for just reference purpose.

Comment: Tushar... Can you please add new steps to create detail link with an example. that will be really helpful to new users to implement the functionality.